# Were the Pharisees and Sadducees asking for some spectacular sign in the sky/heaven in Matthew 16:1?

Tags: matthew, gospels, christology

Matthew 16:1 KJV

> 1 The Pharisees also with the Sadducees came, and tempting desired him that he would show them a sign from heaven

After Christ had performed many miracles the Pharisees and Sadducees still ask for a another sign from heaven.Christ also responds with a reference to the sky in his retort to them

Were they asking for something unusual and spectacular in the sky/heaven in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

In Matthew 15, Jesus performed healing and fed four thousand men. Apparently these "earthly" signs weren't enough for the Pharisees and Sadducees.

Yes, in Matthew 16, they wanted to see some spectacular sign from heaven, perhaps a pillar of fire like in Exodus. Instead of giving them a heavenly sign, Jesus rebuked them with heavenly symbolism  in

> Matthew 16:2 “When evening comes, you say, ‘It will be fair weather, for the sky is red,’ 3and in the morning, ‘Today it will be stormy, for the sky is red and overcast.’ You know how to interpret the appearance of the sky, but you cannot interpret the signs of the times. a 4A wicked and adulterous generation looks for a sign, but none will be given it except the sign of Jonah.” Jesus then left them and went away.

In Matthew's mind, the contrast between earthly and heavenly signs here was deliberate and purposeful.

Comment: +1 I was going to add my own answer based on the [Hermeneia commentary](https://www.amazon.com/Matthew-20-Hermeneia-Historical-Commentary/dp/080066034X) but their answer is basically the same: "After two miraculous feedings in which great crowds participated, and after two mass healings, this demand for a sign is unambiguously malicious. The more precise 'from heaven' that Matthew adds this time intensifies the request and makes clear that the opponents want not a miracle but a cosmic sign"

Comment: +1 coming from you makes me happy :)

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of interesting, or *familiar*, that these fleet-footed, overreaching Religionists would come (spurred on by Satan, most likely: the ultimate tempter!) and "tempt" Him, after He had performed all of these miracles, and it's also somewhat strange (but interesting) that the Pharisees "with" the Sadducees had come *together*. The Pharisees were of the 'extreme' sort, of course, but the Sadducees were unitarians; they didn't believe in the 'supernatural' or the resurrection, which is kind of ironic, considering all of the supernaturalism that had been advancing and overlapping around them at that time!

They came asking for a sign from heaven, in the hopes that Christ would truly show them something, apparently, because they "needed a sign" (the Jew always require a sign, right? Ha!), but Christ goes on to respond to their desires (I would imagine that they may have asked Him to do these things, almost with a sense of pomp in their voices; or, at least, a kind of audible annoyance? or sarcasm? Granted, they *themselves* wanted Him to do something for *them*, *specifically* ['show us a sign from heaven!']).

In verse 3, it says:

> And in the morning, It will be foul weather to day: for the sky is red
>   and lowering. O ye hypocrites, ye can discern the face of the sky; but
>   can ye not discern the signs of the times?

Obviously Christ was holding them accountable for not recognizing Who they were even talking to (hadn't they read their Scriptures?!), and by "signs of the times," he's referring to the signs of the 'end', to realize that The Messiah had come, and the fact that He had come *at that time* should have been something that they recognized was in God's perfect timing!

It goes on in verse 4, which is interesting, too:

> A wicked and adulterous generation seeketh after a sign; and there
>   shall no sign be given unto it, but the sign of the prophet Jonas. And
>   he left them, and departed.

I bet after he 'departed', they were probably scratching their heads, thinking, "What in the world is He talking about?" Or, could it be that Christ references the prophet Jonah to get them to think, to remember the passages, to consider what it means? In previous chapters, Jesus mentions Jonah again (chapter 12). "Think on this, guys!"

Jesus Christ is obviously referring to Jonah's spending the three days and three nights in the belly of the whale, and using that as an example to say, "So will I, but it will be three days and three nights in the belly of the earth!" (referencing His Resurrection, of course).

There are certain commentators that make the 'second fulfillment' of what Jesus is referring to in light of Israel as a Nation: how it will be a sign to them when, idiomatically in the future when the remnant pleas for the Messiah to return and save them, which of course Christ does at the end of the Time of Jacob's (Israel) Trouble, when he returns "after the third day" (hence the parallels to this in Matthew 16:4) and steps in to end it, and then set up his Kingdom here the "new" replenished Earth and henceforth reign for 1,000 years.

Answer (score 0):

The Pharisees and Sadducees are not asking for a spectacular or miraculous sign but are questioning his abilities of predicting the weather. In his answer Jesus criticises their own habit of interpreting the signs in the sky opportunistically. What a dilemma for a weather-prophet in times when modern meteorology was not invented yet, changing your bets by the changes in the outlook of the sky is the logical solution, but not a very fair one for the people who rely on a correct and timely prediction for their choice to travel or not or to harvest or not etc. They are insincere prophets, just like Jonah.